# Hide typo3 content elements for specific user(groups)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to "hide/deactivate" the table element for specific users/usergroups in the typo3 BE. 
Or to be more clear: I want to ONLY allow it to ONE specific user (admin).

How can i do that?

**NOTE:** At the moment the table element is deactivated in the global TS-config via [tt_content removeItems()](https://jweiland.net/typo3/codebeispiele/tsconfig/inhaltslemente-fuer-seiteseitenbaum-deaktivieren.html).

TIA

Comment: you`re talking about BE or FE ?

Comment: I am talking about BE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I have only an old Typo3 4.3.5 installation, but I hope this hasn't changed much.

In User admin, edit group permissions and go to Access lists. At the bottom is "Explicitly allow/deny field values" where you can restrict specific content types.

With the restriction, affected users still see the restricted content element in BE, but get a message when trying to edit it.

Comment: WORKED FOR ME! But the content element is already deactivated generally. So i had to "activate" the element and then "disable" it for one user group which i add all other users to so that only the administrator has it listed. THANKS. P.S: NO its not visible anymore. If explicitly denied, the content element in BE is not visible anymore.

Comment: @d4ny3l Existing content elements of that type are visible for editors, but not editable. But they don't see the element in the "new element" wizard.

Comment: @Jost thats right and also what i actually meant. Its visible if its already included in a page, but not visible as a "new element"...